# Is using the UIKEYBOARD class legal?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikeyboard

I just added a done button on my number keyboard and read that using the keyboard class directly is illegal but some people said that their app was successfully submitted to the app store? Does anyone know if it is legal or not?I have been googling around for 1hr and I keep getting yes and nos.. anyone knows for certain if this will cause the app to get rejected?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not absolutely sure that doing something like adding a DONE button to a numeric keyboard is legal or not. It all depends on Apple, some app is rejected but many apps is already approved by Apple. It is hard to say.

It also depends on your technique as well. Usually, I see that people will work into the UIKeboard view hierarchy to add the DONE button and for this case, the usual approval problems is like I described above, some fail, some succeed

Comment: Many thanks , i will just give it a shot and update this thread on my experiences.